# .htaccess file returns 404 for subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess on my site, which is supposed to redirect to https:// and rewrite URLs like this:

```
http://company.com/product.php
```

Becomes this:

```
https://company.com/product/
```

Here is the current code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^updates/.*\.(zip)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

The problem is that when I try to access a subfolder, for example:

```
https://company.com/subfolder/
```

It returns 404, I'm guessing because it's looking for a subfolder.php file?

I can open the subfolder's index.php file when I enter it like this:

```
https://company.com/subfolder/index.php
```

Can I change this code to preserve the current functionality, but also allow access to subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "not a directory" condition for those rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

`RewriteCond` only applies for the next `RewriteRule` so you have to repeat it.

Comment: It will do an extra useless rewrite of `/invalid-file/` to `/invalid-file.php` rather than directly rendering `/404.php`

Answer (score 0):

Rules should should add `.php` only after checking if corresponding `.php` file exists instead of adding `.php` for every missing file.

Have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^updates/.*\.zip$ - [F,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```